# Question about ${a}_{n+1}$ from the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)!}{(3n)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

By using the ratio test we get $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(n+1)!(n+2)!}{(3n+3)!}}{\frac{n!(n+1)!}{(3n)!}} \right|$. If ${a}_n=(3n)!$ then why is ${a}_{n+1}=(3n+3)!$  instead of ${a}_{n+1}=(3n+1)!$  ? Is $(3n)!$ the same as $3*n!$ in every case?

Comment: Actually, $(3n)!$ is *never* equal to $3\times n!$, unless $n=1$.

Comment: No! Think about $f(x) = 3x^2.$ What is $f(x+h)?$ (Besides, try some cases.)

Comment: $a_{n+1}=(3(n+1))! = (3n+3)!$ . Like Sean said, if $f(x)=4x$ . Then is $f(x+1)=4x+1$ or is it $4(x+1)=4x+4 $?

Comment: For $n=2,$ compare $(3n)!=(3 \cdot 2)!=6!$ to $3 \cdot n!=3 \cdot 2!=6.$ The first is much larger.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a problem with basic algebraic manipulations: if $f(n)=3n$, of course $f(n+1)$ is not $3n+1$ but $3(n+1)=3n+3$. And $f(n)+1=3n+1$. You don't have $f(n+1)=f(n)+1$ for every function $f$!
Likewise, $f(3n)$ is not $3f(n)$ in general.

$$\begin{matrix} n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
n!&1&1&2&6&24&120\\
3\times(n!) & 3 & 3 & 6&18&72&360\\
3n & 0 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12&15\\
(3n)!&1& 6& 720& 362880& 479001600& 1307674368000\\
3n+1&1& 4& 7& 10& 13& 16\\
(3n+1)!&1& 24& 5040& 3628800& 6227020800& 20922789888000\\
3\times(n+1)&3& 6& 9& 12& 15& 18\\
(3\times(n+1))!&6& 720& 362880& 479001600& 1307674368000& 6402373705728000
\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is a clear step for step explanation
$$a_n = \frac{n!(n+1)!}{(3n)!}$$
To get $a_{n+1}$ we substitute (n+1), with the bracket, in place of n. So we get  $$a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)!((n+1)+1)!}{(3(n+1))!} = \frac{(n+1)!(n+2)!}{(3n+3)!}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\frac{(n+1)!(n+2)!}{(3n+3)!}}{\frac{n!(n+1)!}{(3n)!}}$$
Then $(n+1)!$ is cancelled and we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+2)!(3n)!}{n!(3n+3)!} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)} = 0$$